# Reading txt file in separate methods

Tags: java, file, hashset, extends

I have a text file that where I am trying to use different methods to separate specific content in the file and print them depending on what the method is printing out. In this case I am using different methods to separate what countries people have been in, i.e. `john mexico` or `william cuba`. I have made two different classes (main and super class).

This is the super class

```
import java.util.*;

public class myHashSet{


public static HashSet <String> Mexico = new HashSet<>();
public static HashSet <String> Cuba = new HashSet<>();
public static HashSet <String> Jamaica = new HashSet<>();


//only mexico
public void Mexico(){
    Mexico.removeAll(Cuba);
    Mexico.removeAll(Jamaica);

    Iterator <String> m = Mexico.iterator();
    while(m.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.next());
    }

}

//only cuba
public void Cuba(){
    Cuba.removeAll(Mexico);
    Cuba.removeAll(Jamaica);

    Iterator <String> m = Cuba.iterator();
    while(m.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.next());
    }
}

//only jamaica
public void Jamaica(){
    Jamaica.removeAll(Mexico);
    Jamaica.removeAll(Cuba);

    Iterator <String> m = Jamaica.iterator();
    while(m.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.next());
    }
}

//person from every country
public void orCountries(){
    Jamaica.addAll(Mexico);
    Jamaica.addAll(Cuba);

    Iterator <String> m = Jamaica.iterator();
    while(m.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.next());
    }
}

//people who have been to all countries
public void allCountries(){
    Jamaica.retainAll(Mexico);
    Jamaica.retainAll(Cuba);

    Iterator <String> m = Jamaica.iterator();
    while(m.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.next());
    }
}

//only mexico and cuba
public void MexicoandCuba(){
    Mexico.addAll(Cuba);
    Cuba.removeAll(Jamaica);

    Iterator <String> m = Mexico.iterator();
    while(m.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(m.next());
    }
}
}
```

Then this is my main class that should be using methods from the super class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class people extends myHashSet{

public people(String string) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("people.txt"));    
    read(input);
}

public void read(Scanner input){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String name = input.next();
        String country = input.next();
        System.out.println(name + " " + country);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        people p = new people("people.txt");
        p.Mexico();
        p.Cuba();
        p.Jamaica();
        p.orCountries();
        p.allCountries();
        p.MexicoandCuba();
    }
}
```

I know that the issue is that the methods in `myHashSet` aren't reading the file and that's what I am confused on what do to with. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What output do you get? And which methods exactly aren't reading the file?

Comment: The output that I am getting is just the whole text file which is just a list of people and the countries they have been to next to their name like `jack mexico`. And all the methods aren't reading the file, whats printing the file is in the people class. I just dont know how to get my methods to read from the people.txt file.

Comment: the methods don't do anything because you never add anything to your HashSets (whose variables should be lowercase, btw)

Comment: Would I do that by putting HashSets in each method?

Comment: check HashSet#add

Comment: Hm I am trying to do .add for the variable m but you can not do .add with an iterator.

Comment: Scanner#next returns a string.